# Android preferences xml design help needed

Tags: android

I need some help about android preferences to a window XML file, so look what I want:

[image]

for 2) on a picture I create only the line but isn't correct, my code is:

```
<View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="1dp"
  android:background="#A4A4A4"
  android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
/>
```

and my second problem I need this mask code for corners on popup windows like this:

[image]

Comment: There's two separate problems here, so I am voting to put this on hold - questions here need to be asked individually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cardview and second option is you can create  file in drawable and add it in background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cardview and elevation attiribute for the first question. Second question you need to move your view into root parent which has really full width.